# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Error parsing near '<HTML dir="ltr">

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have aspx in sharePoint _layout folder. This page loads user controls from controltemplates folder. User controls has ajax update panels.

I am getting below error when I working with page.

```
Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received
from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response
is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server
 trace
     is enabled.
        Details: Error parsing near '<HTML dir="ltr">
        <H'.
        Line: 4723
        Char: 21
        Code: 0
        URI: http://mysitename.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=5kqA7Nw-EeaK3p4QkMYAWi......
```

Please advise me to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means there was an error in the Ajax response, usually the infamous "Unknown Error" in SharePoint, here are some links to help you understand what happened:

[Ajax Request Monitoring in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome)

[Same deal on Firebug (Firefox)](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/07/02/firebug-network-monitoring-quick-reference-guide.aspx)

If you get the Unknown Error page, simply edit the web.config for the SharePoint site WebApplication (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\virtualdirectories\sitename80\web.config) and change CallStack="true" to see the actual error.

Comment: I dont see any unknow error page and also I have CallStack="true" already there in config file.

Comment: Monitor the call, you won't see the error in your page unless you override the javascript or use the browser, which is easier.