# Using PHP to load html page inhibits any attempt at using up to date css file

Tags: php, html, css, suphp

I have user permissions on my `.html` files other than `0744`. They are actually set to `0700` so to get around this, I have suPHP set up, and I use a `load.php` file to access and load all the files. The file in question is a simple .`html` file like so:

**test.html (0700)**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <p> why is this not working?</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.css (0744)**:

```
body
{
    background-color:#bbcbde;
}    
p
{
    background-color:#bfc4de;
    color:'red' ;
    border:'solid black';
    font-size:35pt;
}
```

**load.php (0744)**:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
header("Location: http://www.example.com/" . $fileName);
exit;
```

Note: the css file I have set to normal 0744 permissions for debugging purposes.

If I type `http://www.example.com/load.php?page=test.html` the page loads find. However, I suspect that the css file is being used from a cache because none of the changes to `test.css` are applied to `test.html`. If I remove the line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
```

The change is reflected as the background becomes white again. However, if I move the `css` file to, for example `test2.css`, and change the style (ie. different colors) and link to that instead, the changes are suprisingly **not** applied. If I move `test.css` to `test2.css` without linking to the new name (similar to deleting the file), the `css` effect is still applied! Similarly if I `chmod` `test.css` to 0000 it still uses the style sheet. Also I know the `.css` file is not corrupted because I con open up `test.html` locally on my machine.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on because I don't have the foggiest.

**EDIT** as per Murray McDonald's answer below, I traced down the problem to having to do with a 304: Not Modified status code. Why Is this being returned when the file has clearly changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my problem (albeit with great support from Murray). I have my folders set up like so

```
/
├── test
│   ├── test.html
│   └── test.css
├── load.php
└── test.css
```

I thought that

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/" . $fileName);
```

would launch the page from within the correct folder, but even if I type the following into the browser

```
http://www.example.com/load.php?page=test/test.html
```

`module.php`, when searching for `test.css` returns `/test.css` and not `/test/test.css` which is what I want. Now, the question is how I tell php to set the working directory.

Comment: Its your web server that resolves URLS and maps them to files in the file system.  Are you using Apache as the server?

Comment: yes apache2.0, and had I typed `http://www.example.com/test/test.html` apache would have been smart enough to load `test/test.css` but for some reason, when returned from `load.php` it's not smart enough to do this. It's like when you do `vim Documents/index.html` and you issue the command `:sh` and you do `ls`, it shows you the folder with `Documents` in it, not `index.html`

Comment: Hi puk -- your load.php is issuing a "Location" header to the client browser -- the client browser is supposed to send in the request in that header -- so in theory there should be no difference between you typing the URL in directly in your browser (http://www.example.com/test/test.html" or if you invoke http://www.example.com/load.php?page=test/test.html)

Comment: But obviously there MUST be some difference -- that's why I am asking you to look at the Apache access logs -- I did LAMP and WAMP development and administration for 8 years (including lots and lots of mod_rewrite and reverse proxying) and I have NEVER EVER even considered changing the working directory in a PHP script - shouldn't be at all necessary if the correct URLS are being requested -- have a good evening!

Comment: @MurrayMcDonald yes that **also** occurred to me that the `Location` header should act as a redirect, so it still should work on files with permission 0700. I too think I am doing something wrong. My initial idea was to use `file_get_contents($fileName)`. Do you think that is better?

Comment: @MurrayMcDonald hey if you are a LAMP expert, what would your advice be on using unix permissions for html? I am currently using suPHP for php/javascript code snippets, but html is much more sensitive. For example, returning it the wrong way might bypass the cache. I highly doubt there is such a thing as suHTML =P

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I run into something mysterious like this I eavesdrop on the HTTP protcol going back and forth between the browser and the server by using "fiddler2" -- it works in MSIE and Firefox.  You can easily see the reuest headers the response headers request body, response body (if any) etc.

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a try. Any advice as to what I should look for?

Comment: An easier solution if you use chrome (or can't get fiddler2 in linux) here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3019085/654789

Comment: well your answer was hugely helpful. It shows 304: Not Modified.

Comment: Yeah that's what one would expect -- the question now is why does it think it hasn't been modified?  Is there an HTTP HEAD request being sent by your browser -- I've seen cases where the file was cached by an ISP and the request isn't even getting to the target server -- you need to look at the server's log to see if the requet is making it o the server -- if it isn't then you need to send out the correct headers to ensure your file can only be cached by the end user and not in any intermediate caches along the way

Comment: I just stated below how I had two `.css` files. All I had to do to fix it was issue a `chdir` command in `load.php` it's funny b/c it was loading `test.html` in the current folder, not in the folder specified by its absolute path =P

Comment: Hmmm -- although that may have worked it can't possibly be the "right solution" -- if you look at your server logs at the request for "http:/yourdomain.com/load.php?page=test/test.thml" following you should see the request generated by having sent out the Location header -- what exacxtly does that request look like?

Comment: They seem to confirm my previous solution: 200 when the `.css` file was loaded, 302 when it had not changed, and 404 when it wasn't found (I moved/deleted it)