# Get marker location on Google maps inside A WEBPAGE

Tags: google-maps

I would like to have the list of marker position, is that possible to get from a webpage that I dont own.

For example i need subsidiary list in this page http://bayi.eshot.gov.tr/ 
When you click "Bayi Sorgula" AJAX request loads the data and creates markers on the google map. Can someone get coordinates, names and address of subsidiaries as a list? What is the way to do this?

Also what is the special word for this data gathering process? Data gathering, mining, crawling? What is the keyword for getting data from a website?

When I inspect elements on browser I may obtain this row for a marker. And this has only top & left px values for absolute positioning.

```
<img style="width: 16px; height: 16px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; left: 338px; top: 416px; z-index: -122731136; cursor: pointer;" src="App_Themes/images/1.png" id="mtgt_unnamed_612">
```

I really dont have further idea about how to do this.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: please update your question with the things you already tried to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution with this feature of Chrome.
[Request Monitoring in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome)

I catch the request data with monitoring and clean it myself.

Thanks anyway.