# Get returned data from PHP to ajax

Tags: php, ajax, return

I have this code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajaxfunctions.php',
        data: {email: email},
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data == "true" || data == "false")
            {
                alert("Response")
            }           
            else
            alert("Data: " + data);
        }
    });
```

with this PHP-Script

```
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
$email = $_POST['email'];
$countEmail = $db->getCountEmail($email);
if($countEmail == 1)
    echo "true";
else {
    echo "false";
}
}
```

The problem is, that it never comes in the alert("Response") case. Always in the other. In the alert window I then got my full index.html content.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to check for string `"true"` not boolean true

Comment: `if(data == "true" || data == "false")`

Comment: Yes soryr, I alaready changed it, but it didn't change the problem

Answer (score 0):

@devShuba monitor your Ajax request in Chrome here is a previous related post
[Request Monitoring in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome)

Comment: The answer from Ajax is just the complete content of the index.html but I don't know why

its always in the else case

Answer (score 0):

maybe the `isset($_POST['email'])` is returning false, that's why.

can you do a `var_dump(isset($_POST['email']));` and check if it evaluates to true?
if no, then you have to check if the email is correctly posted using your javascript.