# Is There Any Way to View and Modify HTTP Requests in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Are there any good plugins or ways to do this in Chrome or even Firefox? I tried using Live HTTP Headers on Firefox and it didn't work (Tried portable and normal). I tried about 10 different ones on Chrome, and the ones that allowed me to send requests didn't let me view sent requests, and the ones that let me view them didn't let me send them...

Comment: Are you looking for implement functionality or for debugging/testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create and view your own HTTP requests, I recommend this tool:

[REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en)

If you are trying to monitor other requests, a detailed answer is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome?rq=1).

Comment: Can you capture requests with REST Console?

Answer (score 1):

In the past i worked with this plugins, and i really recommend you try [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Its great and it is non browser dependant. You can create, manipulate and inspect the http/s request/response and have a lot of addons. Highly recommended. Hope it helps.