# Yii Sort By Clistview not working

Tags: php, yii

I'm using **Yii 1.1.15**. I got to my CListView to populate the table correctly on page load. but when i try to sort the table by `store name` the ajax response is the html for the whole page. and the table is empty.

but when i refresh the page `&sort=store` or `&sort=store.desc` the page works fine and sorts proper too. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

In my Controller

```
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Store', 
                    array(
                        'criteria' => array(
                            'condition'=>$_search_conditions, 
                            'params'=>$search_params,
                        ),
                        'sort'=>array(
                               'defaultOrder'=>'store DESC',
                                'attributes'=>array(
                                    'store'=>array(
                                        'asc'=>'store',
                                        'desc'=>'store DESC',
                                    ),
                                  '*',
                                )
                        ),
                    )
                );

$model = new Store;
$model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

        //render page
        $this->render('index',array(
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                'model'=>$model
        ));
```

In my View

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                        'id' => 'store-list',
                        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                        'itemView'=>'_view',
                        'enableHistory'=> true,
                        'pagerCssClass' => 'pagination',
                        'ajaxUpdate'=>'store-list',
                        'loadingCssClass' => '', //remove loading icon
                        'sortableAttributes'=>array(
                            'store',
                            //'state' => 'State',
                            //'distance' => 'Distance'
                        ),
                        'emptyText' => '<div class="alert alert-info">No data found</div>',
                        'template'=>'
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">     
                                            <div class="pull-left visible-lg visible-md visible-sm">{summary}</div>                     
                                            <div class="pull-right">{sorter}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">{items}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            {pager}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>',
                        'pager' => array('id'=>'_pagination',
                                         'class' => 'LinkPager',
                                         'header' => '', //remove pagination header
                                         'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pagination') //add bootstrap pagination class
                                        ),
                    ));
```

also in my `function parseUrl()` i have this code which does echo the correct value for `$_GET['Store_sort']` the code below is used in my custom url manager class

```
if (!empty($_GET['sort']))
{
    echo $_GET['Store_sort'] = $_GET['sort'];
}
```

UPDATE: even with friendly url disabled it does not sort. here is the URL of the ajax post. The pagination doesnt work either

```
http://localhost/dev/frontend/www/store/store/index/?Store_sort=store.desc&ajax=store-list
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the url of the ajax request?

Comment: Is this still in your code: `echo $_GET['Store_sort'] = $_GET['sort'];`?, because with this you're overwriting the `Store_sort`-GET parameter

Comment: @Dinistro nope, disabled friendly url for now

Comment: Are you sure that the get parameter `Store_sort` is available in the action when you call it with ajax? You can try to print them out with `var_dump`. To look at the ajax request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome

Comment: you mean i have to `$_GET['Store_sort']` in my `actionIndex()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63458/discussion-between-dinistro-and-user2636556).