# Python Scrape with requests and beautifulsoup

Tags: python

I am trying to do scraping excise using python requests and beautifulsoup. 
Basically i am crawling  amazon web page.
I am able to crawl the first page without any issues.

```
r = requests.get("http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/ref=nav_shopall_books_bestsellers")
#do some thing
```

But when I try to crawl the 2nd page with "#2" in urls

```
r = requests.get("http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/ref=nav_shopall_books_bestsellers#2")
```

I see r still has same value that is equivalent to the value of 1 page.

```
r = requests.get("http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/ref=nav_shopall_books_bestsellers")
```

Dont know is #2 causing any trouble while making request to second page. 
I also google about the issues but I could not find a fix. 
What is right way to make request to url with #values. How to address this issue. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to request to the url in the `href` attribute of the anchor tags describing the pagination. It's at the bottom of the page. If I inspect the page in developer console in google chrome I find the first pages `url` is like:

```
http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/ref=zg_bs_books_pg_1?ie=UTF8&pg=1
```

and the second page's url is like this:

```
http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/ref=zg_bs_books_pg_2?ie=UTF8&pg=2
```

`a` tag for the second page is like this:

```
<a page="2" ajaxUrl="http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/ref=zg_bs_books_pg_2?ie=UTF8&pg=2&ajax=1" href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/ref=zg_bs_books_pg_2?ie=UTF8&pg=2">21-40</a>
```

So you need to change the request url.

Answer (score 1):

"#2" is an [fragment identifier](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/), it's not visible on the server-side. Html content that you get, opening "http://someurl.com/page#123" is same as content for "http://someurl.com/page".

In browser you see second page because page's javascript see fragment identifier, create ajax request and inject new content into page. You should [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome) ajax request's url and use it:

[image]

Looks like our url is:

http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/ref=zg_bs_books_pg_2?ie=UTF8&pg=2&aj

Easily we can understand that all we need is to change "pg" param value to get another pages.