# Ajax call for a a url freezes browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a function in view used to transfer a value from a text box to a table displayed on a page. Basically it updates the URL and goes into a function called `update_verified_phone()`. There is another function which is used to update the records using a model named `user_info_model()` and uses controller named `users_info()`.

Problem is when when I use an AJAX function to post to the controller function named `update_verified_phone()`, the browser freezes and hangs up. I was wondering why it is happening?

Sorry just new to AJAX.

Here is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#btnVerify').click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var uid = $('#user_id').val();
            var verified_phone = $('#textNum').val();
            if (isNaN(verified_phone)) 
            {
               alert("Please enter only numbers for user verified_phone");
            }
            else
            {  
                $('#textNum').val('');
                //$.post(base_url+'users_info/update_verified_phone', {uid:user_id,verified_phone:textNum}, function(response)
                //{
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:base_url+'users_info/update_verified_phone',
                    data: {uid:user_id,verified_phone:textNum},
                    //async: true,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        if(data)
                       {   

                           var headingHtml = headingTemplate
                               ({
                                   'verified_phone':data[0].verified_phone,
                                   'verified_timestamp':data[0].verified_time
                               });
                               $('.userinfo').html(headingHtml);
                               $('.userinfo tr td:eq(4)').html(data[0].verified_phone);
                               $('.userinfo tr td:eq(5)').html(data[0].verified_time);
                       }
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is `base_url` in your url??? Where you define it???

Comment: base_url is localhost as I am currently testing it in localhost

Comment: does it freeze during the request or after ? What do you see in your network tab in the dev tools of your browser ?

Comment: @Adi:Its depends on your query and number of records retrieving.

Comment: nothing shows up in network while the browser starts freezing

Comment: Do you get any message in the developer console?

Comment: my query updates two records verified_phone and verified_time (current timestamp)

Comment: no message in developer console , It shows nothing but shows a message on browser chrome ran out of memory

Comment: query also retrieves the new verified phone updated record to the page.

Comment: Try changing `event` to any other variable I suspect it is a keyword

Comment: here is the query in model  function update_verified_phone($user_id,$textNum)
 {
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO history_verified_phone(id,lastverified_phone,lastverified_time,verified_phone,verified_time)
        SELECT $user_id,users.verified_phone,users.verified_time,$textNum,NOW() FROM users WHERE id = $user_id"); 

  $this->db->query("UPDATE users SET verified_phone = $textNum , verified_time = NOW() WHERE id = $user_id");

  $sql= $this->db->query("SELECT verified_phone,verified_time from users WHERE id = $user_id");

  return $sql->result(); 
 }

Comment: textNum is the if of the textbox from where I get the new phone number to update and change and user_id (primary key) I get from a textbox for a record which phone number  needs updation

Comment: tired updating the event  , still browser hangs

Comment: Have you tried adding a `error` method into your `ajax` call? Maybe it's failing?

Comment: nope  , how to add that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to specify JS variable `base_url` correct it out. After that once you check your AJAX request URL response by direct hit from browser address bar and check what if issue is there OR not.

Let me know if you require any more information regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: I have defined base_url in a script tag at the start of the program

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
            var base_url="<?php echo base_url();?>";
            var type="list";
            var fileName="";
            var fileExt="";
        </script>

Comment: Ok and have check that response of your request by passing it into new tab..? 

Paste your URL(Example : www.DOMAIN.com/users_info/update_verified_phone/YOURPARAMTER') and check this page take response quickly or not?

Comment: gave Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'users.verified_phone,users.verified_time,,NOW() FROM users WHERE id =' at line 2

INSERT INTO history_verified_phone(id,lastverified_phone,lastverified_time,verified_phone,verified_time) SELECT ,users.verified_phone,users.verified_time,,NOW() FROM users WHERE id =

Filename: C:\Users\fab\Desktop\Tptt\server\UniServerZ\www\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: This error message may seem cryptic at first. That is because it is a general MySQL error pointing to a syntax error of some sort in the SQL Query statement.  So could you please share your query for review? we need check it first there is some silly error so we need to correct it first.

Comment: Please share your MySql query which already set/wrote. This issue error is regarding that query and need to correct it.

Comment: INSERT INTO history_verified_phone(id,lastverified_phone,lastverified_time,verified_phone,verified_time) 
SELECT $user_id,users.verified_phone,users.verified_time,$textNum,NOW() FROM users WHERE id = $user_id 

UPDATE users SET verified_phone = $textNum , verified_time = NOW() WHERE id = $user_id"

SELECT verified_phone,verified_time from users WHERE id = $user_id

Comment: these are the 3 queries  , I am returning the result of last one to the web page

Comment: Please check I have added solution as new answer...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty difficult but I try to solve it.

Query 1: Insert query with `SELECT` statement

```
//If history_verified_phone:id is auto incremental then no need to cover it into INSERT statement so removed.
$instVerified = "INSERT INTO history_verified_phone(lastverified_phone,lastverified_time,verified_phone,verified_time) 
SELECT users.verified_phone,users.verified_time,'". $textNum ."',NOW() FROM users WHERE id = '". $user_id ."'";
```

Query 2: Update query

```
$updtUser = "UPDATE users SET verified_phone = '" . $textNum . "', verified_time = NOW() WHERE id = '" . $user_id . "'";
```

Query 3: Select query

```
$selUser = "SELECT verified_phone,verified_time from users WHERE id = '" . $user_id . "'";
```

Please replace variable with your query, `$instVerified` for Query 1, `$updtUser` for Query 2 and `$selUser` for Query 3 and after that please check what happen. Because I have some doubt with your given query may failed and that is the reason for issue.

Please let me know what is outcomes here.

Comment: history_verified_phone:id is not auto incremental

Comment: I checked the previous query in MySQL and it was working .I checked for a particular id  say id=10 and updated and inserted accordingly. Since I needed only to display updated phone and updated time so I just saved the query 3rd in a variable.

Comment: OK, so you can use below query instead Query 1:

`$instVerified = "INSERT INTO history_verified_phone(id,lastverified_phone,lastverified_time,verified_phone,verified_time) 
SELECT '". $user_id ."'", users.verified_phone,users.verified_time,'". $textNum ."',NOW() FROM users WHERE id = '". $user_id ."'";`


Let me know what is it finally done OR any error?

Comment: Not sure what that quotes and dots around variables do eg:'". $textNum ."' as they are giving errors

Comment: Still the browser freezes.

Comment: dots and quotes are used for concatenation of strings. check it [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement). What about error. It present that what it say?

Comment: '".textNum."'  gives nearly 15 errors in the view file. I tried to remove those quotes and executed the program still it does same thing. It freezes

Comment: Also errors are gone right? Please check it with AJAX response. How it see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome).

Comment: I used 'textNum' instead '".textNum.'" . Errors got removed  , but still browser is freezing when ever I run that ajax request.

Comment: I cant see anything in resources . That means errors are gone.

Comment: so have you checked that response is 200 OK and result is given what you expect..?

Comment: Still the problem is there, without any errors .... the main problem is  , Ajax call for a a url freezes browser.

Comment: If this problem is from live site then please me URL OR you need check console of bug tracker.

Comment: can you share me your contact?

Comment: Feel free to contact me at narendra.addweb@gmail.com.

Comment: Yes, no worries. Send me request over or provide me yours ID.

Comment: mine is adilogin10@gmail.com