# My AJAX form isn't sending to my PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
function sendForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('percentageOfMessages', $('#percentageOfMessages').val());

    if ($('RemoveDeletedAccounts').prop('checked')) {
        formData.append('RemoveDeletedAccounts', "1");
    } else {
        formData.append('RemoveDeletedAccounts', "0");
    }

    if ($('RemoveNoReply').prop('checked')) {
        formData.append('RemoveNoReply', "1");
    } else {
        formData.append('RemoveNoReply', "0");
    }

    if ($('RemoveNoResponse').prop('checked')) {
        formData.append('RemoveNoResponse', "1");
    } else {
        formData.append('RemoveNoReply', "0");
    }

    formData.append('minMatchPercent', $('#minMatchPercent').val());
    formData.append('minDistance', $('#minDistance').val());
    formData.append('maxDistance', $('#maxDistance').val());

    formData.append('blacklistUsernames', $('#blacklistUsernames').val());

    formData.append('pickuplineText', $('#pickuplineText').val());

    formData.append('userEmail', $('#userEmail').val());

    formData.append('Username', $('#Username').val());
    formData.append('Password', $('#Password').val());


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',

        xhr: function() { // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) { // Check if upload property exists
                //myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        url: 'addAccounts.php',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, err) {
            console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
            console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

}
```

This is the ajax code I have for sending a form. I enabled `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` in my 'addAccounts.php' page just to see what the errors are.

The first error I got was that `$RemoveNoResponse = $_POST["RemoveNoResponse"];` was an invalid index. So just to double check, I put `$RemoveNoResponse = "0";` and I got another error saying `$minDistance = $_POST["minDistance"];` was an invalid index.

I went ahead and tested it and I don't believe the error is in my PHP.

Do you guys see anything wrong with my Ajax code?

Here is a bit of the HTML

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="RemoveNoResponse" name="RemoveNoResponse">
    <label for="RemoveNoResponse">Remove conversations you didn't get a Response Back from</label>

    <input type="text" name="minDistance" id="minDistance" value="0" />
    <i>Minimum distance between you and your match</i>
</div>
```

And part of the PHP

```
$percentageOfMessages = $_POST["percentageOfMessages"];
$RemoveDeletedAccounts = $_POST["RemoveDeletedAccounts"];
$RemoveNoReply = $_POST["RemoveNoReply"];
$RemoveNoResponse = $_POST["RemoveNoResponse"];
$minMatchPercent = $_POST["minMatchPercent"];
$minDistance = $_POST["minDistance"];
$maxDistance = $_POST["maxDistance"];

$blacklistUsernames = $_POST["blacklistUsernames"];
$pickuplineText = $_POST["pickuplineText"];
$userEmail = $_POST["userEmail"];
$Username = $_POST["Username"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];

//$captcha = $_POST["captcha"];
//$num1 = $_POST["num1"];
//$num2 = $_POST["num2"];


if (empty($percentageOfMessages)) {
    echo "percentageOfMessages";

}elseif (empty($minMatchPercent)) {
    echo "minMatchPercent";

}elseif (empty($minDistance)) {
    echo "minDistance";

}elseif (empty($maxDistance)) {
    echo "maxDistance";

}elseif (empty($pickuplineText)) {
    echo "pickuplineText";

}elseif (empty($userEmail)) {
    echo "userEmail";

}elseif (empty($Username)) {
    echo "Username";

}elseif (empty($Password)) {
    echo "Password";
```

Comment: have you tried to check the XHR request to see if the data is sent at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome

Comment: Do you really need all this `formData` stuff? It seems you can do with just `$('form').serialize()` if you handle the checkboxes on the server-side.

Comment: @Eduard7 , I feel like it must be, because I don't get any error about 'percentageOfMessages' and that's the first thing in the PHP file

Comment: @jeroen I never learned it any other way :/

Comment: `$('RemoveDeletedAccounts')` and other selectors, where are your `#`'s ?

Comment: If you are not uploading any files and the form contains all the fields you need to send, you can use `data: $('form').serialize(),` in your ajax call. Saves you some typing next time :-)

Comment: @teran , I don't believe you need the #'s

Comment: @jeroen, omg. I just looked it up. You're amazing. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @teran , Although I'm not sure why not... Cause it seems to be working now after GavGrif's response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if its an issue: but this seems wrong:

```
   if ($('RemoveNoResponse').prop('checked')) {
        formData.append('RemoveNoResponse', "1");
    } else {
        formData.append('RemoveNoReply', "0");
    }
```

should it be :

```
   if ($('RemoveNoResponse').prop('checked')) {
        formData.append('RemoveNoResponse', "1");
    } else {
        formData.append('RemoveNoResponse', "0");
    }
```

reading that your error was "$RemoveNoResponse = $_POST["RemoveNoResponse"];"  was an invalid index, this would make sense in that due to this typo -  $_POST["RemoveNoResponse"] would not have been "0" if that checkbox was not checked - throwing the error in the php which expected a value for that variable.

Comment: LOL. Omg that was the issue.

Comment: glad to help. thanks :) - also just note that if you are using the serialize() as described above, and you have more  than one form on that page - you will need to specify (by id or name) which form is to be serialized for the Ajax submission.