# Error 404 page not found in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

i am using WordPress platform with PHP AND MYSQL  in order to create a website where i have a page that includes 4 dropdown lists  that get it data from the MYSQL database and using javascript and AJAX i am trying to make these dropdown list dependent on each other where the user select from teh first one and based on the user's selection the second drop down display data.

the problem is that i have used 2 codes in order to make AJAX work without refreshing the hall page.

when i try to select from the first dropdown list in the debug mode it display:

**404 drpdown_fetch_owner.php error page not found**

directory structure :

**/opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wp-portfolio/search_info_location.php**

**/opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wp-portfolio/dropdown_fetch_owner.php**

tables:

- site_info:

  - siteID
  - siteNAME
  - ownerID
  - List item

owner_info:

- ownerID
- ownerNAME

problem :

after the user click on the first droplist
variable **ownerID** in the AJAX stay empty and do not get any value.

i added `var_dump($sql);` under the SQL query in the **dropdown_fetch_owner.php** code
 and i got this statement in the debug mode:

**/opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wp-portfolio/dropdown_fetch_owner.php:6:
array (size=0)
  empty**

## code1 :

```
<form method ="post" action ="" name="submit_form">
    <table border="0" width="30%">
        <tr>
           <td>Site Name</td>
           <td>Owner Name</td>
           <td>Company Name</td>
           <td>Subcontractor Name</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">

             <?php


                 $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT siteNAME  from site_info");
                  foreach($query_site_name as $row)
                  {
        //           $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                   echo "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";
                  } 

             ?>

            <!--create  dropdown list owner names-->
            </select></td>

            <td><select id="owner_name"  name ="owner_name">
            <option value="">Select Owner</option>


    <!--  the below part  of code work as it should   --!>
        <!--create  dropdown list site names-->

        <form method ="post" action ="" name="submit_form">
            <table border="0" width="30%">
                <tr>
                   <td>Site Name</td>
                   <td>Owner Name</td>
                   <td>Company Name</td>
                   <td>Subcontractor Name</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">

                     <?php


                         $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT siteNAME  from site_info");
                          foreach($query_site_name as $row)
                          {
                //           $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                           echo "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";
                          } 
                     ?>

                    <!--create  dropdown list owner names-->
                    </select></td>

                    <td><select id="owner_name"  name ="owner_name">
                    <option value="">Select Owner</option>

  <script type="text/javascript">

// make Dropdownlist depend on each other
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#site_name').change(function(){
         var ownerID = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
            url:"dropdown_fetch_owner.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{ownerID:ownerID},
            datatype:"text",
            success:function(data){
                $('#owner_name').html(data);
            }

         });
       });

    });

</script>
```

## dropdown_fetch_owner.php:

```
<?php
 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-load.php');
 global $wpdb;

$sql =$wpdb->get_results("select * from owner_info where ownerID = '".$_POST['ownerID']."' ORDER BY ownerNAME");

echo '<option value="">Select Owner</option>';
foreach($sql as $row){

//while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID."'>".  $row->ownerNAME."</option>";
}


?>
```

Comment: could you please share the directory structure of the files

Comment: @TamilSelvanC    i added the file structure

Comment: change like this `url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/dropdown_fetch_owner.php",` in `$.ajax({`

Comment: why you couldn't use the wordpress ajax https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: i did not know about the AJAX plugin for wordpress.

your answer has solved this problem but know i have another problem the variable is empty

Comment: why `var_dump($sql);` is empty array. copy the sql and run it in phpmyadmin, is it result a rows

Comment: when i tried on phpmyadmin and replace **'".$_POST['ownerID']."'**  with an ID it works fine

Comment: look the browser console and change the site id and see network tab and click that link dropdown_fetch_owner.php and see what result it shown

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wordpress, use ajax(https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Change

```
url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/dropdown_fetch_owner.php",
```

instead of `url:"dropdown_fetch_owner.php",`

Comment: can you take a look on the second problem that i faced now ?

Comment: what issue is that

Comment: after the user select from the first dropdown list the vaiable in AJAX  still empty and the second drodown list doesn't display any value.

Comment: can you please share full code or describe your problem