# How to show success message on top of my form after submissin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Currently my success message appears only next to submit button once the form is submitted.Also my form doesn't clear the fields after the submission and stays the same, but it does work in terms of sending email. How can I show my success message in a new div instead of my form?

My form:

```
<section class="inspiration" id="three">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <article class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <div class="intermediate-container">
            <div class="heading wow fadeInUp">
              <h2>יש לכם שאלה? צרו איתי קשר</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="col-md-6 center-block col-sm-6 ">
                <form id="mc-form" method="POST">
                  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp">
                    <label for="name" hidden>שם פרטי</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="cv form-control" placeholder="שם פרטי">
                    <span class='error-message' id='name-error'></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp ">
                    <label for="phone" hidden>טלפון</label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="cv form-control" placeholder="טלפון">
                    <span class='error-message' id='phone-error'></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-xs-12  wow fadeInUp">
                    <label for="email" hidden>דואר אלקטרוני</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="cv form-control" placeholder="דואר אלקטרוני">
                    <span class='error-message' id='email-error'></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp ">
                    <label for="subject" hidden>נושא</label>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="cv form-control" placeholder="נושא">
                    <span class='error-message' id='subject-error'></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-xs-12  wow fadeInUp">
                    <label for="message" hidden>הודעה</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="cv form-control message" placeholder="השאירו את הודעתכם פה" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                    <span class='error-message' id='message-error'></span>
                  </div>
                  <!-- <input type="submit" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-custom-outline " value="שלח" > -->
                  <button class="btn btn-custom-outline wow fadeInUp" id="submit-button">שלח</button>
                  <span class='error-message' id='submit-error'></span>
                  <span class="success">Thank's for submitting the form</span>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

My script:

```
function sendForm() {
  $('[id*="-error"]').text(''); 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './send.php',
    data: $("#mc-form").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
        Object.keys(data['error']).forEach(function(key) {
          producePrompt(data['error'][key], key+'-error', 'red');
        });
      }
      if(data.hasOwnProperty('mail_error')) {
        alert('Could not send mail');
      }
      if(data.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
        $('.success').show();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you get in the return? I mean, give a `console.log(data)` inside `success: function(data) {` and tell us what's happening, so that we can do something.

Comment: Closing it as dupe as not enough info given plus this is almost exact dupe.

Comment: I tried to do console.log(data); but it does not show anything . My form also goes thought sever side validation. That duplicates doesn't help me much either

Comment: Your question doesn't help us either. Would you like to post the PHP code and also the Network tab output? Without that we can't even think of helping you. Although at first glance, your code looks good.

Comment: Here's my php : https://pastebin.com/Mz3S2peA

Comment: What  do you mean by Network tab output?

Comment: Okay, so you have Chrome browser right, Press F12 and find the network tab. Clear everything in the network tab and then click on the submit to see any AJAX requests captured there.

Comment: Check this out for more info and update the post with the relevant details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome Also update your question by adding the PHP code in there.

Comment: In my XHR I got 200 status .In my XHR preview: {success: []}
success
:
[] and in my response: {"success":[]}

Comment: So it looks like your function doesn't output anything...