# output variable value to console in "remote" request jquery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am using "remote" request option of jquery Validate plugin and also data is passed.

Is there any way to check what value is passed in the request?

I want to output **userID** variable that is being passed.

Here's a part of validation:

```
            personal_email: {
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    param:{
                        url: app.baseurl('user/check_personal_email'),
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: 
                        {
                            userID : function()
                            {
                                return $("#userID").val();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    // ,
                    //  depends: function(element)
                    //  {
                    //      return ($('#editTrue').val() == undefined && $('#editTrue').val() == null);
                    //  }
                }
            },
```

And here's the controller's function that handles the request and send the result:

```
public function checkPersonalEmailExists($f3)
{
    $userID = $f3->get('POST.userID');
    echo "<script>console.log( 'User ID: " . $userID . "' );</script>";
    $email = $f3->get('POST.personal_email');
    $user = new UserModel();
    $records = $user->checkIfPersonalEmailExists($email);

    if(count($records) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($records as $record) 
        {
            $user_id = $record['id'];
        }
        echo ($userID == $user_id) ? 'true' : 'false';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

I tried `echo "<script>console.log( 'User ID: " . $userID . "' );</script>";`.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `echo "<script>console.log( 'User ID: " . $userID . "' );</script>";` need to be `echo $userID;`

Comment: I don't think that works in the middle of a request... not working... :(

Comment: `remote` is looking for `user/check_personal_email`, but your function is named `checkPersonalEmailExists`.... that can't be working?

Comment: PHP constructs the page on the server at the time it's first loaded.   You can't `echo` something after an Ajax submission since you're not reloading the page.  And if you did reload the page, that would defeat the whole purpose of using Ajax in the first place.  You'd have to have Ajax loaded on the page ahead of time and trigger it when you need.

Comment: If you want to see what values are sent within the Ajax request, you can just inspect the Ajax request directly from your browser's developer's tools.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome