# Created two different PHP Laravel contact forms both submit and send at the same time when you complete one form

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I have created two different contact forms using PHP Laravel, AJAX and Mailgun. Both forms are working as they both send mail via Mailgun. However, when you complete and send one form, it automatically sends the other form for some reason.

Here is the jQuery(AJAX) I used to send the mail:

```
$("form.wpcf7-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var token = $("input[name=_token]").val(); // The CSRF token
    var first_name = $("input[name=first-name]").val();
    var last_name = $("input[name=last-name]").val();
    var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var phone = $("input[name=phone]").val();
    var bodyMessage = $("textarea[name=message]").val();

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/contact',
       dataType: 'json',
       data:{_token: token, first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name, email:email, phone:phone, bodyMessage:bodyMessage},
       success:function(data){
           $(".email-success-messge").append(data.success).fadeIn(999);

       }
    });
});

$("form.reservation-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var token = $("input[name=_token]").val(); // The CSRF token
    var fullname = $("input[name=fullname]").val();
    var phone = $("input[name=phone]").val();
    var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var number_of_guests = $("select[name=number_of_guests]").val();
    var date_of_reservation = $("input[name=date]").val();
    var time_of_reservation = $("input[name=time]").val();

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/dine',
       dataType: 'json',
       data:{_token: token, fullname:fullname, phone:phone, email:email, phone:phone, number_of_guests:number_of_guests, date_of_reservation:date_of_reservation, time_of_reservation:time_of_reservation},
       success:function(data){
           $(".email-success-message").append(data.success).fadeIn(999);

       }
    });
});
```

My ReservationController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use Mail;
use Session;

class ReservationController extends Controller
{
    public function postReservation(Request $request){

        $data = array(
            'fullname' => $request->fullname,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'number_of_guests' => $request->number_of_guests,
            'date_of_reservation' => $request->date_of_reservation,
            'time_of_reservation' => $request->time_of_reservation
        );

        Mail::send('emails.reservation', $data, function($message) use ($data){
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('jafar@calmcollective.co.uk');
            $message->subject('Reservation Details');
        });

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Thank you for making your reservation with us!'], 200);

    }
}
```

My ContactController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use Mail;
use Session;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function postContact(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email'] );

        $data = array(
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'bodyMessage' => $request->bodyMessage
        );

        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('jafar@calmcollective.co.uk');
            $message->subject('Contact Details');
        });

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Thank you for getting in touch!'], 200);

    }
}
```

My routes

```
Route::post('/contact', 'ContactController@PostContact');

Route::post('/dine', 'ReservationController@postReservation');
```

Screenshot of my XHR requests: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: What about your routes? Can you post the code?

Comment: @SebastienD pardon me, I forgot. I have added it to the question now.

Comment: When you post your data, what does your console say ? Are there XHR requests on both routes?

Comment: And `ContactController@PostContact` in your route should be `ContactController@postContact`

Comment: @SebastienD nothing is outputted in the console.

Comment: I should have been more precise, in your `Network` tab of your development tools (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3019085/7652544)

Comment: @SebastienD Ok I have provided a screenshot of XHR requests. They both have a 200 status but I know this because the contact forms still sent mail.

Comment: If both requests are sent, the error stand in your HTML. Maybe a conflict in the structure that causes both ajax requests to be called. Post a bit more of HTML code :)

Comment: @SebastienD I figured it out. You were right it was my HTML. My Form element had the same classes when you submitted on the form it would send the other.

Comment: Ok, mark your question as answered then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post, there is surely an error in your HTML, a conflict between classes which causes a double Ajax call