# Laravel update mysql table return empty data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, datatables

I am developing an application where i display/edit/delete data from Mysql table using laravel and datatables. I get this error when trying to add or edit data and update it in Mysql table:

[image]

[image]

Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Datatables Server Side Processing in Laravel</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <br />
    <h3 align="center">Datatables Server Side Processing in Laravel</h3>
    <br />
    <div align="right">
        <button type="button" name="add" id="add_data" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Add</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table id="student_table" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th><button type="button" name="bulk_delete" id="bulk_delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="studentModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" id="student_form">
                <div class="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title">Add Data</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <span id="form_output"></span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                     <input type="hidden" name="student_id" id="student_id" value="" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="button_action" id="button_action" value="insert" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="action" value="Add" class="btn btn-info" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#student_table').DataTable({        
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('ajaxdata.getdata') }}",
        "columns":[
            { "data": "first_name" },
            { "data": "last_name" },
            { "data": "action", orderable:false, searchable: false},
            { "data":"checkbox", orderable:false, searchable:false}
        ]
     });

    $('#add_data').click(function(){
        $('#studentModal').modal('show');
        $('#student_form')[0].reset();
        $('#form_output').html('');
        $('#button_action').val('insert');
        $('#action').val('Add');
        $('.modal-title').text('Add Data');
    });

    $('#student_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('ajaxdata.postdata') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.error.length > 0)
                {
                    var error_html = '';
                    for(var count = 0; count < data.error.length; count++)
                    {
                        error_html += '<div class="alert alert-danger">'+data.error[count]+'</div>';
                    }
                    $('#form_output').html(error_html);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#form_output').html(data.success);
                    $('#student_form')[0].reset();
                    $('#action').val('Add');
                    $('.modal-title').text('Add Data');
                    $('#button_action').val('insert');
                    $('#student_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }
            }
        })
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#form_output').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{route('ajaxdata.fetchdata')}}",
            method:'get',
            data:{id:id},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#first_name').val(data.first_name);
                $('#last_name').val(data.last_name);
                $('#student_id').val(id);
                $('#studentModal').modal('show');
                $('#action').val('Edit');
                $('.modal-title').text('Edit Data');
                $('#button_action').val('update');
            }
        })
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this data?"))
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('ajaxdata.removedata')}}",
                mehtod:"get",
                data:{id:id},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#student_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }); 

    $(document).on('click', '#bulk_delete', function(){
        var id = [];
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this data?"))
        {
            $('.student_checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                id.push($(this).val());
            });
            if(id.length > 0)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('ajaxdata.massremove')}}",
                    method:"get",
                    data:{id:id},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#student_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Please select atleast one checkbox");
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Student;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;

class AjaxdataController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
     return view('student.ajaxdata');
     //http://127.0.0:8000/ajaxdata
    }

    function getdata()
    {
     $students = Student::select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name');
     return DataTables::of($students)
            ->addColumn('action', function($student){
                return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary edit" id="'.$student->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete" id="'.$student->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete</a>';
            })
            ->addColumn('checkbox', '<input type="checkbox" name="student_checkbox[]" class="student_checkbox" value="{{$id}}" />')
            ->rawColumns(['checkbox','action'])
            ->make(true);
    }

    function postdata(Request $request)
    {
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name'  => 'required',
        ]);

        $error_array = array();
        $success_output = '';
        if ($validation->fails())
        {
            foreach($validation->messages()->getMessages() as $field_name => $messages)
            {
                $error_array[] = $messages;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($request->get('button_action') == "insert")
            {
                $student = new Student([
                    'first_name'    =>  $request->get('first_name'),
                    'last_name'     =>  $request->get('last_name')
                ]);
                $student->save();
                $success_output = '<div class="alert alert-success">Data Inserted</div>';
            }

            if($request->get('button_action') == 'update')
            {
                $student = Student::find($request->get('student_id'));
                $student->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
                $student->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
                $student->save();
                $success_output = '<div class="alert alert-success">Data Updated</div>';
            }

        }
        $output = array(
            'error'     =>  $error_array,
            'success'   =>  $success_output
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    function fetchdata(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $student = Student::find($id);
        $output = array(
            'first_name'    =>  $student->first_name,
            'last_name'     =>  $student->last_name
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    function removedata(Request $request)
    {
        $student = Student::find($request->input('id'));
        if($student->delete())
        {
            echo 'Data Deleted';
        }
    }

    function massremove(Request $request)
    {
        $student_id_array = $request->input('id');
        $student = Student::whereIn('id', $student_id_array);
        if($student->delete())
        {
            echo 'Data Deleted';
        }
    }
}
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('ajaxdata', 'AjaxdataController@index')->name('ajaxdata');
Route::get('ajaxdata/getdata', 'AjaxdataController@getdata')->name('ajaxdata.getdata');

Route::post('ajaxdata/postdata', 'AjaxdataController@postdata')->name('ajaxdata.postdata');

Route::get('ajaxdata/fetchdata', 'AjaxdataController@fetchdata')->name('ajaxdata.fetchdata');
Route::get('ajaxdata/removedata', 'AjaxdataController@removedata')->name('ajaxdata.removedata');
Route::get('ajaxdata/massremove', 'AjaxdataController@massremove')->name('ajaxdata.massremove');
```

Only delete is working. Also i want to use `select-checkbox` attribute of datatable but it doesn't work, like this one [link](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html) for the line color on selection but with multiple selections.

Comment: Do you need to pass a CSRF token in the ajax request? _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}" ?

Comment: Yes, i need to do that.

Comment: Laravel is RESTFul framework for update use or submit your data with PUT method, if you are submitting form with jquery ajax set method PUT. also use URL postdata/id of record

Comment: The same error occures.

Comment: Can you show your update function in JSFile?

Comment: I showed the entire part of the edit/update related code function.

Comment: You are passing only id to backend(which is data).... But you are trying to get student_id on the request...

Comment: I am using a hidden field for student_id.

Comment: Your question is not clear @Sami You need to share all related data! Share your `edit` and `update` button/form code please.

Comment: What error do you see in the [network-tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3019085/1766219)?

Comment: @Iftikhar uddin i had to post another concern so stackoverflow accept the entire code. I hope they will update this in the future.

Comment: @Zeth that is mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Alaksandar Jesus Gene i solved this issue by changing the `post` request by a `get` request for the `postdata` function inside web.php file and inside the view related script code. Now that it works my second concern still unresolved.

Answer (score -1):

Can u try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function () {

    data = {};
    data.id = $(this).attr("id");
    data.first_name = "User"; //$('#first_name').val();
    data.last_name = "hello"; //$('#last_name').val();
    data.student_id = $(this).attr("id");
    data.action = 'Edit';
    data.button_action = 'update';
    $('#form_output').html('');
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('ajaxdata.fetchdata')}}",
        method: 'post',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
           // $('#studentModal').modal('show');
           // $('.modal-title').text('Edit Data');
           console.log("data", data);

        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log("err", err);              
       }
    })
});

Route::post('ajaxdata/postdata', 'AjaxdataController@postdata')->name('ajaxdata.postdata');
```

The router expects post request but you are sending GET request. Please change the method as shown

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. can you update your answer so i can approuve it ?

Comment: What was the issue? If you have solved let me know, as i have updated my answer

Comment: I have updated my answer. please mark it correct, as this is a frequent mistake we do and it will be useful to others.

Comment: I have a confusion here ... you are mapping to url: "{{route('ajaxdata.fetchdata')}}", which points to GET request. But the url is going for url: "{{route('ajaxdata.postdata')}}", I dont know, might be you have posted an updated code.

Comment: But that's not what i meant,  you have deleted your comment that contains the correct answer.

Comment: I can't delete your comment. Please post your answer and give me credits with @Alaksandar. Its fine with me.