# USGA - GHIN 2nd Page Information - Get The Info from a 2nd web page after an XML log in

Tags: html, xml, vba, authentication

I got excellent help from "asmitu" who helped me log-in to the USGA GHIN site with the following code.   However, my real end problem was to log-In and then maneuver to this 2nd URL (“https://www.ghin.com/golfer-lookup/following“) to extract my data that is stored on the 2nd URL page.  Is there a way to modify the code below so that I land on the 2nd page after login?

```
Sub GHIN_Login()

Const Url = "https://api2.ghin.com/api/v1/public/login.json?"
Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, ghinNum$, lastName$

ghinNum = ""            'put your ghinNum here
lastName = ""           'put your lastName here

With Http
  .Open "GET", Url & "ghinNumber=" & ghinNum & "&lastName=" & lastName & "&remember_me=false", False
  .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
  .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.ghin.com/login"
  .send
End With

MsgBox Http.responseText
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of that target page generates dynamically, so you can't parse the required fields using xhr. However, the following attempt should lead you grab the json response having required fields within it.

```
Sub GetInformation()
    Const Url = "https://api2.ghin.com/api/v1/public/login.json?"
    Const Link = "https://api2.ghin.com/api/v1/followed_golfers/"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, ghinNum$, lastName$

    ghinNum = ""
    lastName = ""

    With Http
        .Open "GET", Url & "ghinNumber=" & ghinNum & "&lastName=" & lastName & "&remember_me=false", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.ghin.com/login"
        .send
        .Open "GET", Link & ghinNum & ".json", False
        .send
    End With

    MsgBox Http.responseText
End Sub
```

Comment: Looking a the string of data that comes back from the "MsgBox Http.responseText" there was nothing from the menu structure there.  So I also tried, "MsgBox Http.responseXML" and "MsgBox Http.responseStream" but those broke the code

Comment: After you initial glogon, there code re-directs me to a site called "https://www.ghin.com/profile" which is where a hader menu appease that give me the choice I need.

Comment: https://www.ghin.com/profile: <div class="s-navigation" id="heaöer" style=”top: 0px;"> ► <header>-.</header>
V<nav class="navigation">
T<div class=''container">
^<ul class="nav links">
▼ <li>
<a class="nav link" href=’’/post-score >Post Score</a>
</li>
▼ <li>
a class^ nav link href^ '/golfer-lookup Golfer Lookup /a
</li>
► <li>-</li>

Comment: Check out the update @Ringo Boinker. I think the issue is resolved.

Comment: This  solution was elegant and perfect.  It will force me to study how you built the URL pointers you used in your solution.   Fantastic!