# I'm not able to POST data using JavaScript Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm able to get the data from the filltext web api using Ajax GET request ,but when i use Post request then i can't see anything returned to the console and also no errors, how do i solve this?

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'http://www.filltext.com/?rows=1&pretty=true&id={index}&fname={sahil}&lname={keshav}&company={business}';

let test = JSON.stringify({
    id:124,
    fname:'sunil',
    lname:'singh',
    company:'reebok'
}); 

function getData(){ 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
            let tes = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
            console.log(tes);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST',url,true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');
    xhr.send(test);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do a `POST` request? FillText.com seems to provide only an endpoint for `GET`.

Comment: So we can't update the value and get it back on our console? but manually we can.

Comment: @sahil did you try btw with status code in a range  between 200-400?

Comment: @RahulDwivedi i'm just new to this request concept , i'm trying since 3 days but i cannot proceed further please if you have any resource to share so i can study from it .

Comment: Just replace your condition to this `if(this.readyState === 4 && (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400))` and try once as I said in the answer

Comment: @RahulDwivedi after using the code provided by you the code is working , but i'm unable to add those properties in the object.When i go to the Network tab and under preview it's just showing an empty array.

Comment: It says you must have 20 reputation to chat , can you give me your whats app number if possible please i'm really frustated with this thing , you might be a help to me please.

Comment: @sahil As much as I'd like to help, that's not how SO works. Even if I provide you the number, somebody would flag it and it'd be removed :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to console log all the information that will help you debug the request, and add an error handling function as well.

Also, the Developer Console is your friend. Check the browser's console and the Networks Tab (Chrome) to figure out what's going on. Make sure to check the XHR option in the Network's Tab to display only the XMLHttpRequest network requests.

Here's a [**StackOverflow post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome#answer-3019085) that can help you in that direction.

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'http://www.filltext.com/?rows=1&pretty=true&id={index}&fname={sahil}&lname={keshav}&company={business}';

let test = JSON.stringify({
           id:124,
           fname:'sunil',
           lname:'singh',
           company:'reebok'
}); 
    function getData(){ 
       xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
           console.log( "onReadyStateChange:", xhr.readyState, xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
           if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
               let tes = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
                 console.log(tes);
          }
      }
       xhr.open('POST',url,true);
       xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');
       xhr.send(test);
       // Add error handling:
       xhr.onerror = function(){
           console.log( "onError:", xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
           // Triggers when request couldn't be completed
       }
     }
```

Comment: So please can you tell me what's going wrong , why isn't my request being completed or can you provide with with link so i can understand the post request . I want to do with pure JavaScript not with JQuery.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to an SO post that can help you figure out what's going on with the POST request and its response.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you can POST to the http://www.filltext.com/ API? I am not sure that the current service supports POST requestss.

Comment: @Kostan i'm not sure wether POST works on the filltext api but manually you can add data an object Press enter the values get updated , but i have a feeling that we can post it too

Comment: If the server does not support POST requests, you cannot POST and will get back an error message. Working with objects and data in the realm of JS is another thing though.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're making a `POST` request here, you *probably* need to check the status between `200` to `400`. (I'm including 400 since after this *typically* codes for bad requests start)

`this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400`

Here are the links:

[MDN- POST status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201)

[MDN-statuses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

> 201 Created The request has succeeded and a new resource has been
>   created as a result. This is typically the response sent after POST
>   requests, or some PUT requests.

Further clarifications: Typical status code for a successful `POST` request is 201. This is **NOT** to say that you can't send a `200` code for `POST` request. But that doesn't happen usually and I believed that's where the mistake in the code could be.