# i am new to ajax and jquery so i dont know what is wrong in my code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am a beginner in coding and am learning ajax but my code is not working can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo.txt", success: function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

this is demo.txt

```
<h2>jQuery and AJAX is FUN!!!</h2>
<p id="p1">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

this is my console error
[image]

Comment: Right click - > inspect -> console tab . Also , for checking ajax request check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome)

Comment: @Dark Potato Gaming Your web page must be running on a web server like Apache, IIS, NodeJS. If you choose Apache server, you could use AppServ. Source: https://youtu.be/DJZvbk23eoI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN6UF.jpg)

This is how your URL can use ajax, because Ajax has cross domain restrictions

If you are using vscode editor, you can download the "live server" plug-in and right-click in HTML to open the web page

Comment: so do i have to use a server plugin. without it ajax will not work

Comment: You can also use a server like Apache, but using Apache may be a little troublesome. Anyway, you can use ajax as long as you make the URL a network address instead of opening it as a local file

Answer (score 0):

Pls follow the documentation provided at
[jQuery.ajax() | jQuery API Documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjmivmZnv_tAhXO4zgGHZALDoAQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.ajax%2F&usg=AOvVaw0SVmx5D7Hke6VyWoecyxyF)

It should work fine when you include in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Little information about Ajax. Why do we use ajax, Ajax is mostly used for sending data from Javascript to the Back-end server. Lets say if you want to get the user input from front-end and you want to store the data in your database. Ajax comes to help.

Example of a simple ajax function with passing user data (namely data1 and data2):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: { 
        user_data1   : data1,
        user_data2   : data2,
    },
    url: YOUR_FUNCTION_PATH,
    success: function(data){
        // After success passing data to YOUR_FUNCTION
        // Handle what you do next
    },  
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        // Error of passing data to YOUR_FUNCTION
        // Debug to see what is wrong
    }
});
```

Then in your `YOUR_FUNCTION` and if you sending data to PHP function,

```
$user_data1 = $_POST['user_data1'];
$user_data2 = $_POST['user_data2'];
```

If you are using the old one, `CodeIgniter`, it is pretty simple to get the data.

```
$user_data1 = $this->input->post('user_data1');
$user_data2 = $this->input->post('user_data2');
```

Answer (score -1):

Your URL may need to start with localhost, for example: http://localhost :8080

Comment: Please explain also