# Scrape ajax pages

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I do not anything how to scrape ajax pages there is no pagination on website the website will be load by clicking the `load more button` these is the page link https://aaos22.mapyourshow.com/8_0/explore/exhibitor-gallery.cfm?featured=false

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
import pandas  as pd

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url="https://aaos22.mapyourshow.com/8_0/explore/exhibitor-gallery.cfm?featured=false",
            wait_time=3,
            screenshot=True,
            callback=self.parse,
            dont_filter=True
        )
        
    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//h3[@class='card-Title\nbreak-word\nf3\nmb1\nmt0']//a//@href").extract()
        
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)
            
    def parse_book(self, response):
        title = response.css(".mr3-m::text").get()
        
        address = response.css(".showcase-address::text").get()
        address=address.strip()
        
        
        website = response.xpath("//li[@class='dib  ml3  mr3']//a[starts-with(@href, 'http')]/@href").get() 
        website=website.strip()
        
        phone = response.xpath("//li[@class='dib  ml3  mr3'] //span[contains(text(), 'Phone:')]/following-sibling::text()").get()
        phone=phone.strip().replace("-","")
        
        
        yield{
            'title':title,
            'address':address,
            'website':website,
            'phone':phone
            
        }
```

Comment: So whare are you stuck exactly? To click on **Load More Results** button?

Comment: yes I am stuck on `Load More Results button` when I click they show  result but I do not know how I scrape data from it

Comment: Which info are you trying to scrape?

Comment: `title` `address` `website` `phone`

Comment: I don't see you scraping `title`, `address`, `website`, `phone` in your code trials either.

Comment: I have edit the code now you can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, try the following script to get all the fields you wish to grab from there traversing all the exhibitor list:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MapYourShowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mapyourshow"

    content_url = 'https://aaos22.mapyourshow.com/8_0/ajax/remote-proxy.cfm'
    inner_base = 'https://aaos22.mapyourshow.com/8_0/exhibitor/exhibitor-details.cfm?exhid={}'

    headers = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    }
    params = {
        'action': 'search',
        'searchtype': 'exhibitorgallery',
        'searchsize': '557',
        'start': '0',
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            url=self.content_url,
            method='GET',
            headers=self.headers,
            formdata=self.params,
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    def parse(self,response):
        for item in response.json()['DATA']['results']['exhibitor']['hit']:
            inner_link = self.inner_base.format(item['fields']['exhid_l'])
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=inner_link,
                headers=self.headers,
                callback=self.parse_content,
            )

    def parse_content(self,response):
        elem = response.json()['DATA']['BODYHTML']
        sel = Selector(text=elem)
        title = sel.css("h2::text").get()
        try:
            address = ' '.join([' '.join(i.split()) for i in sel.css("p.showcase-address::text").getall()])
        except AttributeError: address = ""
        website = sel.css("a[title*='website']::text").get()
        phone = sel.xpath("normalize-space(//*[starts-with(@class,'showcase-web-phone')]/li[./*[.='Phone:']]/span/following::text())").get()
        yield {"title":title,"address":address,"website":website,"phone":phone}
```

Comment: can you tell me  that how you get this link `https://aaos22.mapyourshow.com/8_0/ajax/remote-proxy.cfm`                                              `https://aaos22.mapyourshow.com/8_0/exhibitor/exhibitor-details.cfm?exhid={} `

Comment: Give this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3019085/9189799) a go to get clarity on it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used your code and did it rather my way (because I'm not a huge fan of selenium). But I hope this helps anyway:

```
import requests
import json
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

params = {
    'action': 'search',
    'searchtype': 'exhibitorgallery',
    'searchsize': '200', # don`t increase this too much (increase the start parameter instead and send a new request after some delay)
    'start': '0',
}

response = requests.get('https://aaos22.mapyourshow.com/8_0/ajax/remote-proxy.cfm', params=params, headers=headers)

data = json.loads(response.text)

all_sites = []
for exs in data["DATA"]["results"]["exhibitor"]["hit"]:
    id = exs["fields"]["exhid_l"]
    site = f"https://aaos22.mapyourshow.com/8_0/exhibitor/exhibitor-details.cfm?exhid={id}"
    all_sites.append(site)

for site in all_sites:
    response = requests.get(site)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    info_box = soup.find("div", {"id":"showroomContentDiv"})
    title = info_box.find("section", {"id":"scroll-description"}).text.strip().split("\n")[0][6:]
    address = " ".join(info_box.find("p", {"class":"showcase-address"}).text.strip().split())
    website = info_box.find("ul", {"class":"showcase-web-phone"}).find_all("li")[0].text.strip()
    phone = info_box.find("ul", {"class":"showcase-web-phone"}).find_all("li")[1].text[7:].strip()

    print(title)
    print(address)
    print(website)
    print(phone)

    # delay so you don't create too much traffic
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: but the inner page has no json how than I scrape this is page they have no json inside it t https://aaos22.mapyourshow.com/8_0/exhibitor/exhibitor-details.cfm?exhid=1388830

Comment: You can use e.g. beautifulysoup in order to extract the data you wish. I update my answer so you can see

Comment: Updated it, although you already got another answer. At least, you can see that there are also other ways ;)