# Auto buy price in buff163

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, xml-parsing, steam

I want to get this number (dollar price) [image: auto buy price].

```
def get_auto_buy_price(self):
        id = 35650 # specital number for items
        url = f"https://buff.163.com/goods/{id}?from=market#tab=buying"
        html = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
        print(soup.find_all("div", "detail-tab-cont"))
```

With this code I can get where buff163 contains tables with prices but it's empty.

Comment: Were you able to automate the mapping of market_hash_name<->buffID ?

Comment: @lightyears99 I found in github code with database of all skins in buff163. https://github.com/andrevsantos/buff163_bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the webpage is dynamic and data is populating  from external source via API. Only `requests` module can grab data from `API` url.

```
import requests
res= requests.get('https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/buy_order?game=csgo&goods_id=35650&page_num=1&_=1657808768032').json()

for price in res['data']['items']:
    print(price['price'])
```

**Output:**

```
1.2
1.1
1
1
1
0.8
0.1
```

[API_SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Xye.png)

Comment: Can you send me reference to the buff163 api?

Comment: You can know more about api from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome/3019085#3019085