# Cannot find tags using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am stuck with this seemingly simple task that I would like to develop in Python with the Beautifulsoap library.

From this [URL](https://media.pearsoncmg.com/curriculum/intl/it/newlab/9788883395642/myapp_sb_starter/#!/activity/10175864) I'd like to be able to find and collect all the names assigned to the audio files presented on the page.

From an analysis of the code, the names I'm looking for are indicated as in this example line:

`<html-echo class = "collection-title style-scope player-app"> 001 - The alphabet - Exercise 1 </html-echo>`

However when I run this code below, the result is always an empty list.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
TARGET_URL = "https://media.pearsoncmg.com/curriculum/intl/it/newlab/9788883395642/myapp_sb_starter/#!/activity/10175864"
req = requests.get(TARGET_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content,'html5lib')
results = soup.findAll("html-echo",{"class": "collection-title style-scope player-app"})
print(results)
```

Can you help me understand where I'm wrong?

A thousand thanks

g

Answer (score 1):

Data is loaded dynamically by JavaScript from external url which is called API.That's why bs4 can't pull the required data.

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url= 'https://media.pearsoncmg.com/curriculum/intl/it/newlab/9788883395642/myapp_sb_starter/assets/10175864.json?callback=jQuery21309753537890012054_1664892076397&_=1664892076398'
headers={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
data=[]

res=requests.get(api_url,headers=headers)
#print(res)
for item in res.json()['asset']:
    title = item['title']
    data.append({'title':title})

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                        title
0            001 - The alphabet - Exercise 1
1            002 - The alphabet - Exercise 2
2            003 - The alphabet - Exercise 3
3                 004 - Colours - Exercise 4
4                 005 - Colours - Exercise 5
5                 006 - Numbers - Exercise 2
6                 007 - Numbers - Exercise 3
7                 008 - Numbers - Exercise 5
8                 009 - Numbers - Exercise 6
9                 010 - Numbers - Exercise 7
10                   011 - Pets - Exercise 2
11  012 - this/that/these/those - Exercise 4
12       013 - Classroom objects- Exercise 2
13                   014 - a/an - Exercise 3
14     015 - Classroom language - Exercise 2
15     016 - Classroom language - Exercise 4
16     017 - Classroom language - Exercise 6
17               018 - The time - Exercise 2
18               019 - The time - Exercise 3
19               020 - The time - Exercise 4
20                   021 - Days - Exercise 1
21                   022 - Days - Exercise 3
22                 023 - Months - Exercise 6
23                024 - Seasons - Exercise 9
24               025 - Seasons - Exercise 10
25        026 - School subjects - Exercise 2
26        027 - School subjects - Exercise 3
27        028 - School subjects - Exercise 4
28      029 - Parts of the body - Exercise 2
29                030 - Plurals - Exercise 3
30             031 - Appearance - Exercise 2
31             032 - Appearance - Exercise 4
32              033 - Exit test - Exercise 1
```

**see the screenshot**

[pic-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIzgd.png)
[pic-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7z9l.png)

Comment: You can take help about API how it works from the following discussions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome/3019085#3019085

Comment: how do I find api_url in this case? Since I have similar cases to manage with different url. Thanks

Comment: Please, read the answers  attentively