# Scraping href links in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I am trying to scrape the links that are stored in the href values from this website: https://www.fotmob.com/teams/8676/fixtures/wycombe-wanderers?page=1

[image: Here is a photo of the links]

I tried the following code:

```
url = "https://www.fotmob.com/teams/8676/fixtures/wycombe-wanderers?page=1"
r = requests.get(url)
html_doc = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

[tag['href'] for tag in soup.find_all('a',{'class':'css-11smhdq-FtContainer e1ym2d3s2'})]
```

But this just returns an empty list. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you see those links in your soup object?

Comment: @JuanC I can yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required data is loaded dynamically by JavaScript that's why you are getting empty output because bs4 can't render JS but they are using API and you can extract data from API url instead.

```
import requests

api_url= 'https://www.fotmob.com/api/teams?id=8676&timezone=Asia%2FDhaka&ccode3=BGD'
headers={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
data=[]

res=requests.get(api_url,headers=headers)
#print(res)
for item in res.json()['fixtures']['allFixtures']['fixtures']:
    url = item['pageUrl']
    data.append({'url':'https://www.fotmob.com' + url})
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915857/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-burton-albion'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915859/matchfacts/bolton-wanderers-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3917827/matchfacts/northampton-town-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915875/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-shrewsbury-town'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915880/matchfacts/exeter-city-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915866/matchfacts/barnsley-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 
'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3992753/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-bristol-city'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915922/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-charlton-athletic'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3940648/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-tottenham-hotspur-academy'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915928/matchfacts/fleetwood-town-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915936/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-accrington-stanley'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915957/matchfacts/derby-county-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3940645/matchfacts/stevenage-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915945/matchfacts/sheffield-wednesday-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915987/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-plymouth-argyle'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915978/matchfacts/oxford-united-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915997/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-peterborough-united'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3940637/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-peterborough-united'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916030/matchfacts/milton-keynes-dons-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 
'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916003/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-cambridge-united'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916015/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-morecambe'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3915901/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-port-vale'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/4050422/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-walsall'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916041/matchfacts/forest-green-rovers-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916064/matchfacts/cheltenham-town-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916055/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-portsmouth'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916098/matchfacts/lincoln-city-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916093/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-ipswich-town'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916109/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-bristol-rovers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916141/matchfacts/plymouth-argyle-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916154/matchfacts/peterborough-united-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916114/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-oxford-united'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916126/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-sheffield-wednesday'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916124/matchfacts/bristol-rovers-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916164/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-fleetwood-town'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916202/matchfacts/port-vale-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916186/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-derby-county'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916187/matchfacts/accrington-stanley-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916247/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-bolton-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916223/matchfacts/shrewsbury-town-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916231/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-exeter-city'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916228/matchfacts/burton-albion-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916285/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-barnsley'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916279/matchfacts/charlton-athletic-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916314/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-milton-keynes-dons'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916321/matchfacts/ipswich-town-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916303/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-forest-green-rovers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916358/matchfacts/morecambe-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916335/matchfacts/cambridge-united-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916349/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-lincoln-city'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916377/matchfacts/wycombe-wanderers-vs-cheltenham-town'}, {'url': 'https://www.fotmob.com/match/3916378/matchfacts/portsmouth-vs-wycombe-wanderers'}]
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCwmR.png)

Comment: Thats brilliant, thanks so much. How did you know that it had an API and where did you find the url for it?

Comment: Thanks. You will find a couple of discussions about API from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome/3019085#3019085

Comment: Thanks for sending that. I can't see on that link though how you found what headers to use?

Comment: Ok wait. I will show you screenshot

Comment: Open the website then click on F12 to go to network tab then refresh the url from far top left circular icon  and see the above screenshot:

Comment: I see, thanks so much for your help. You are a hero!