# <script> can not be found under <div id="xxxxx">

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web-scraping the historical price with python from this URL.

https://www.dotproperty.co.th/en/condo/2945/nai-harn-beach-condominium

I checked developer tools on chrome browser, there is the information I'd like to get in the `<script>` which is located under the `<div id="market-stats">` I had attached the image of the elements. I used beautifulsoup to scrape out the data but it seems like that information in the `<script>` never appears in the terminal. My assumption is this section of information may not be allow for scraping?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.dotproperty.co.th/en/condo/2945/nai-harn-beach-condominium"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
data = soup.find('div', id_ = 'market-stats')


print(data)
```

[image: Elements from developer tools showing the information exists]

Comment: Hey, you have to understand the basics of web-scraping. What you are doing is fetching the Markup of a site and then parsing it, searching for an element that does not exist in the Markup itself but is created through Javascript later in the browser. Your method will not work. Go and check it yourself, the Markup that the server sends includes an empty DIV with the id "market-stats".

Comment: Highly appreciated for clarifying that. Is there any possibility to get that information created by javascript? (if you don't mind me asking, I'm still learning web scraping)

Comment: Yes, there is. I have checked how the data is retrieved, an API endpoint that requires some kind of authentication (maybe invisible captcha), no chance there. The easiest possibility after that would be to use Python Selenium (Emulating a browser). You'd have to make Selenium scroll down the page (because the data is only loaded when you scroll down to the section), wait some time for the data to be retrieved and query the element with Selenium. There are countless tutorials for Selenium for Python. Maybe give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an  example how to grab the required script tag from API response and rest of your task.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dotproperty.co.th/en/condo/2945/nai-harn-beach-condominium'
headers={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url,headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
token = soup.select_one('meta[name="csrf-token"]').get('content')

header = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-csrf-token': token,
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    
}
api_url= 'https://www.dotproperty.co.th/en/market-stats/project-page/condo/?key=2945&pv_id=sea_th_pv_4df81b83-00a9-4453-97b3-80c92eea45b9'

data=[]

res=requests.get(api_url,headers=header).json()['msg']
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())
script = soup.find('script').get_text(strip=True)
print(script)
```

**Output:**

```
function getChartDataSets(type) {
            var chartData = {
                                'sale': {
                    data : {
                        dataSets : {
                            'left':{
                                // yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
                                radius: 0,
                                data:[4850000,4962500,4770833],
                                borderColor: "rgb(79,190,75)",
                                backgroundColor: "rgb(79,190,75)",
                                fill:false,
                                showLine:true,
                                label:'Median sale price'
                            },
                                                        'right': {
                                // yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
                                radius: 0,
                                data:[4917801,5167798,5124463],
                                borderColor: "rgb(204,51,51)",
                                backgroundColor: "rgb(204,51,51)",
                                fill:false,
                                showLine:true,
                                label: 'Mueang Phuket' + ' Median sale price'
                            }
                                                    }
                    },
                    yAxes : {
                        min: 4450000,
                        max: 5450000,
                        stepSize: 250000,
                    }

                },
                                                'sqmSale': {
                    data : {
                        dataSets : {
                            'left':{
                                // yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
                                radius: 0,
                                data:[88867,94915,94594],
                                borderColor: "rgb(79,190,75)",
                                backgroundColor: "rgb(79,190,75)",
                                fill:false,
                                showLine:true,
                                label:'Median sale price/sqm.'
                            },
                                                                                            'right': {
                                    // yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
                                    radius: 0,
                                    data:[97669,91350,92066],
                                    borderColor: "rgb(204,51,51)",
                                    backgroundColor: "rgb(204,51,51)",
                                    fill:false,
                                    showLine:true,
                                    label: htmlDecode('Mueang Phuket' + ' Median sale price/sqm.')
                                }
                                                                                    }
                    },
                    yAxes : {
                        min: 83000,
                        max: 103000,
                        stepSize: 5000,
                    }

                },
                                                            }
            return chartData[type];
        }
        function getDataSets(chartType){
            var dataSetsAr = getChartDataSets(chartType);
            var dataSets;
            if (dataSetsAr.data.dataSets.right) {
                datasets = [dataSetsAr.data.dataSets.left, dataSetsAr.data.dataSets.right];      
            }else{
                datasets = [dataSetsAr.data.dataSets.left];
            }
            var dataSets = {
                labels: ["Sep 2022","Oct 2022","Nov 2022"],
                datasets: datasets
            }
            return dataSets;
        }
        function getOptions(chartType){
            var dataSetsArr = getChartDataSets(chartType);
            // console.log(getChartOptionsDataSets(chartType).scales.left.ticks.max);
            var options = {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'bottom',
                    onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
                      var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
                      var ci = this.chart;
                      var alreadyHidden = (ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden === null) ? false : ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden;
                      var anyOthersAlreadyHidden = false;
                      var allOthersHidden = true;

                      // figure out the current state of the labels
                      ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
                        var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);

                        if (i !== index) {
                          if (meta.hidden) {
                            anyOthersAlreadyHidden = true;
                          } else {
                            allOthersHidden = false;
                          }
                        }
                      });

                      // if the label we clicked is already hidden
                      // then we now want to unhide (with any others already unhidden)
                      if (alreadyHidden) {
                        ci.getDatasetMeta(index).hidden = null;
                      } else {
                        // otherwise, lets figure out how to toggle visibility based upon the current state
                        ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
                          var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);

                          if (i !== index) {
                            // handles logic when we click on visible hidden label and there is currently at least
                            // one other label that is visible and at least one other label already hidden
                            // (we want to keep those already hidden still hidden)
                            if (anyOthersAlreadyHidden && !allOthersHidden) {
                              meta.hidden = true;
                            } else {
                              // toggle visibility
                              meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !meta.hidden : null;
                            }
                          } else {
                            meta.hidden = null;
                          }
                        });
                      }
                      if (!allOthersHidden && !anyOthersAlreadyHidden && !alreadyHidden) {       
                         delete ci.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min
                         delete ci.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max
                         delete ci.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.stepSize
                      }else{
                         updateChart();
                         return;
                      }
                      ci.update();
                    },
                },
                hover: {
                  mode: 'nearest',
                  intersect: false,
                },
                title:{
                    display: false,
                    text: 'Median Sale'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    intersect: false,
                    mode: 'index',
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                            return ' ฿' + addCommas(label);
                        }
                    },
                //     custom: function(tooltip) {
                        //         if (!tooltip) return;
                        //         // disable displaying the color box;
                        //         tooltip.displayColors = false;
                        //     },
                },

                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        // padding: 100,
                        display: true,

                        gridLines : {
                           display : false
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        gridLines : {
                           display : true
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            // beginAtZero:true,
                            fontColor: "rgb(79,190,75)",
                            min:dataSetsArr.yAxes.min,
                            max: dataSetsArr.yAxes.max,
                            stepSize: dataSetsArr.yAxes.stepSize,
                            fontSize: 10,
                            beginAtZero: false,
                            userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
                                value = value.toString();
                                return '฿' + nFormatter(value);
                            }
                        },
                    }]
                }
            }

            return options;
        }
        var ctx = document.getElementById("market-stats-chart").getContext('2d');
        var chartType = $('#market-stats-type').val();

        marketStatsChart = new Chart(ctx, {
           type: 'line',
           data: getDataSets(chartType),
           options: getOptions(chartType)
       });
    //    document.getElementById('indicator-graph-panel').style.display = 'none';
       function updateChart(){
           var newType = $('#market-stats-type').val();
           var newDataSets =  getChartDataSets(newType);


           var dataSets;
           if (newDataSets.data.dataSets.right) {
               datasets = [newDataSets.data.dataSets.left, newDataSets.data.dataSets.right];     
           }else{
               datasets = [newDataSets.data.dataSets.left];
           }

           marketStatsChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = newDataSets.yAxes.min;
           marketStatsChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = newDataSets.yAxes.max;
           marketStatsChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.stepSize = newDataSets.yAxes.stepSize; 

           marketStatsChart.data.datasets = datasets;
           marketStatsChart.update();
       }
       $('#market-stats-type').on('change', updateChart);

       function nFormatter(num) {
            if (num >= 1000000000) {
                return ( Math.round( ((num / 1000000000) * 100)) / 100).toFixed(1)   + 'B';      
            //    return (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'G';
            }
            if (num >= 1000000) {
                return (Math.round( ((num / 1000000) * 100) )  / 100 ).toFixed(1)+ 'M';
            //    return (num / 1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M';
            }
            if (num >= 1000) {
                return (Math.round( ((num / 1000) * 100) )  / 100).toFixed(1) + 'K';
            //    return (num / 1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K';
            }
            return num;
       }
```

Comment: May I ask how did you found the ```api_url= 'https://www.dotproperty.co.th/en/market-stats/project-page/condo/?key=2945&pv_id=sea_th_pv_4df81b83-00a9-4453-97b3-80c92eea45b9'```

Comment: You will find a couple of discussions about API from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820927/request-monitoring-in-chrome/3019085#3019085

Comment: Alright, crystal. I can't thank you enough. Highly appreciated these details.